# Move tool feature in digitizing toolbar doesn't work/ not available

Tags: qgis-plugins

I can't move any polygons and the layer is in the edit mode, but the move feature button in the digitizing toolbar doesn't appear to be enabled to click it.

[image: Selected Layer is in edit mode, but can't click the move tool button]

Comment: What is the data provider? (PostGIS, Shapefile etc)

Comment: @JGH The data is from protected planet (wdpa.org). I was able to move polygons when i started using qgis, i cant remember the version. But with the new updates I can't get the digitizing tools, move feature button to work. I mean it's always like that.